# How to show that $4n^2 +20n\log(n)+2000n+4 \log(n)+1111$ is in $\Theta(n^2)$?

Tags: algorithms

I am practising these types of questions for more understanding. But I am not getting how to show it is in $\Theta(n^2)$. I tried solving to show it is in ${O}(n^2)$ but I am not sure my approach to this problem is correct or not. Can you please help me to understand?

I did a few observations as $\log(n) \leqslant n$ for all $n > 0$ so we can replace $\log(n)$ with $n$. Also $n \leqslant n^2$ for all $n \geqslant 1$. So this way I'll get

$$4n^2 + 20n\log(n) + 2000n + 4 \log(n) + 1111 \leqslant 4n^2 +20 (n^2)+ 2000n + 4(n) +1111,$$ for $n>0$.

With another estimation, I've considered $$n \leqslant n^2$$ for $n > 0$, so replacing $n$ with $n^2$ yields to

$$4n^2 + 20n^2 + 2000n + 4n +1111 \leqslant 4n^2 + 20n^2 + 2000n^2 + 4n^2 + 1111,$$ for $n>0$,
which is less or equal to
$$4n^2 + 20n^2 + 2000n^2 + 4n^2 + 1111n^2,$$  since $1111 \leqslant 1111 n^2$  for   $n > 0$.

This yields to $3136n^2$ and if I pick $n_0$ for $0$ my $C$ would become $3136$, hence $g(n)$ is in ${O}(f(n))$ as $g(n) \leqslant C \cdot f(n)$ by letting $C=3136$ and $n_0 \geqslant 0$.

Is this way correct? Also, can you help me to get big-$\Omega$ equation for the given $f(n)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your reasoning is correct. In summary, you have obtained that
$$4n^2\leqslant 4n^2 + 20n\log n+ 2000n+ 4 \log n+ 1111 \leqslant 3136n^2,$$
for all $n\geqslant 1$, which is precisely what it means to be $\Theta(n^2)$ (as $n\to\infty$).

---

For big-$\Omega$ (assuming you are referring to [Knuth's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#The_Knuth_definition)), we just need to show that for all $n\geqslant A$ (for some fixed $A$), the function $f(n) = 4n^2 + 20n\log n+ 2000n+ 4 \log n+ 1111 $ is larger than some fixed multiple of $n^2$.

But this is obviously true for $n\geqslant 1$ since
$$4n^2 + \underbrace{20n\log n+ 2000n+ 4 \log n+ 1111}_{>0} \geqslant 4n^2 = \Omega(n^2).$$

Comment: Why it is not n>= 0?

Comment: Because $\log 0$ is undefined.

Comment: @PrasannaSasne Also it doesn't really matter, if i can show that it holds for $n\geqslant A$ for some fixed constant $A$, that would be enough. (e.g. if it was only valid for $n\geqslant 273$ then that would still make it $\Theta(n^2)$)

Comment: will you please show it to me for big-Omega(f(n))? I am really struggling to show it mathematically

Comment: @PrasannaSasne I will edit my answer.